# Saving multiple screenshots

Tags: c#

My goal is to capture screen shots of the entire desktop.

I have set the timer to 5 second interval just for testing purposes.

I am using this code for screenshots:

```
int screenLeft = SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Left;
int screenTop = SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Top;
int screenWidth = SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Width;
int screenHeight = SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Height;
using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(screenWidth, screenHeight))
{
    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
    {
        g.CopyFromScreen(screenLeft, screenTop, 0, 0, bmp.Size);
    }

    bmp.Save(screenPath);
}
```

As for the screen path

```
string screenPath = @"c://EventScout/Screen " + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") + ".png";
```

Everything is working just fine aside from the fact that I end up only with one screenshot.

What am I doing wrong? Any ideas, or leads?

Comment: First you don't need the `bmp.Dispose()` as this will automatically be disposed by the `using` statement.  That most likely isn't your issue just a note...

Comment: Where exactly do you set the screen path?  Have you debugged to see that it is at least changing as you expect?

Comment: If you only get one screenshot, maybe your timer isn't working. Where's the code that sets that up?

Comment: I think Jeffrey has the answer- OP needs to clarify where that string assignment is, and (most likely) move the assignment within the loop, or timer event, or w/e the call is for this.

Comment: Thank you for the answer the screenpath was not in the loop, and that was the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the file name you are saving to on each iteration.

Comment: He does... Happens every 5 seconds (from question) and then appends file name with DateTime.Now. Edit: Or at least is eluding to it where he points out string screenPath = "". For OP, place that screenPath assignment inside the loop.

Comment: Thank you for the answer the screenpath was not in the loop, and that was the problem